# Create single python executable module

Tags: python, linux, winapi, executable

Guys, I have much python code in modules which are resides in several python packages and now I need to create single python executable module or file which will include all these files, so it will be working on windows and on linux servers. What are possible solutions and how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what egg files are for.  Read this: [What are the advantages of packaging your python library/application as an .egg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953/what-are-the-advantages-of-packaging-your-python-library-application-as-an-egg-f)

Answer (score 10):

For windows use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) , for linux use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and for Mac use [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)

Using these tools you can have a `setup.py` which based on os will build the final binary.

I have tried all three and they work well, or you can use [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) they claim to be cross-platform

Comment: @mavnn but I have found py2exe much better

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) can help you ..

> py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.

Tutorial > http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: thank you and it obviously can help for windows but what about linux?
Do you know if there is way to have one application but support several operation system?

Answer (score 1):

You can [kivy](http://kivy.org/) for python cross plat form application .

> Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
>   that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps