# Conversion of directory which contains python and shell script to binary (.elf format)

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, binary, converters

Conversion of directory which contains python and shell script to binary (.elf format)

i want to convert a directory which contains shell script and python script to a linux binary format such that i can run in linux machine.

please help me on this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On linux, use [Pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999129/create-single-python-executable-module) for more info on how to generate executable files, or packaging modules.