# What are the benefits and downsides of using the Python packaging *.egg format over a simple directory with setup.py?

Tags: python, packaging, egg

When I release a program, I usually just create a setup.py and put it on pypi. It's installable with pip, I can always share it easily with others. It works for me, and apparently for a lot of people.

I see the benefit of making an exe, a deb or a rmp to easy sysadmin.

But I really don't see the point of using eggs. Can you tell me what can I gain from it ?

I also once read that eggs had downsides, but I can't find the article anymore. Could you describe to me what problems using this packaging format can cause ?

Please note that I did saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953/what-are-the-advantages-of-packaging-your-python-library-application-as-an-egg?rq=1), but the answer is also applicable to a simple directory with setup.py. It doesn't tell me the benefits of eggs over the simpler format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eggs are tied to a specific architecture and python version, and until Python 3.3, if the egg contains C extensions, even the internal Unicode representation size (UCS2 vs. UCS4).

Unfortunately, the latter difference is not captured in the egg metadata; an egg filename contains the architecture and the python version (major.minor, so 2.4 or 3.1) but the unicode byte size is omitted.

Because of this, eggs are not very portable. A `.tgz` or `.zip` distribution on the other hand, is (hopefully) platform agnostic. Your installation tool, be it `easy_install`, `pip`, `buildout` or whatever, knows how to compile a python package distribution into an egg for you, so you generally *avoid* distributing the `.egg` files altogether.

The only exception is Windows, where most people will be lacking the toolchain to compile C extensions. As Windows distributions of Python default to UCS2, you are *usually* safe to distribute Windows `.egg` builds of packages with C extensions, to facilitate installation by automated tools.

If you use the `setup.py` script to create the distribution, it's trivial to create a source-only package for upload to PyPI. I can recommend the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for more information.

Comment: If you are interested in an example, take [Acquisition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Acquisition); the PyPI page includes a source distribution, plus Windows binary eggs.

Answer (score 1):

*.egg is a pure *deployment* format that is used after having a package installed through easy_install or pip.

Is does not make sense uploading files as .egg to PyPI. People doing this have no idea what they are doing.

A proper PyPI release is either a .tar.gz archive, or a .zip archive or .exe file (for Windows binaries e.g.) but NEVER EVER a *.egg file.

Comment: Ok, but why would use use .egg in deployment over fetching the lib with pip, rsync it, git pulling it, scp it or just use it in a pip bundle ?

Comment: No, eggs *were* designed as a distribution format too! But they failed at that task, as they did not take wide-unicode builds into account. So, *in practice* we ended up using .eggs as a deployment format only. Python 3.3 will change all that, btw.