# Using pypiserver to install Python egg files

Tags: python, pip

I have to be missing something simple, but I have just set up a pypiserver (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver) and have been unable to use it to install egg files.  It will serve tarballs (tar.gz files), but seemingly not eggs.  When I request the egg via "pip install" the pypiserver records an HTTP 200 (it records a 303 when I give it a bogus package name), but the pip install responds with "No distributions at all found for ".

Am I missing something or is this simply not supported?  If not, what would be a recommended alternative for a quick and easy pypi server?  There seem to be several options.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think pip always downloads sources and compiles them. 
Easyinstall can install from eggs as well.

See [Pip compared to easyinstall](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/other-tools.html#pip-compared-to-easy-install):

> pip doesn’t do everything that easy_install does. Specifically:
>
> It cannot install from eggs. It only installs from source. (In the future it would be good if it could install binaries from Windows .exe
>   or .msi – binary install on other platforms is not a priority.)

Comment: `easy_install` also can install from source; pip ignores eggs altogether.

Comment: Another thing I'd make clear: It's not the pypyserver setup, it would not work with pypi.python.org *either*. Use source tarballs instead.

Comment: Well that certainly explains why I can't make it work.  Thanks very much for the clarification.

Comment: And last but not least, you should use source distributions unless you *absolutely* need eggs. See [What are the benefits and downsides of using the Python packaging *.egg format over a simple directory with setup.py?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278091/12278547#12278547)